# Put a String from Facebook API in to a Listbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In the current client I am using (control rather), the way to receive/parse a request is:

```
        var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
        string id = result["id"].ToString();
        string name = result["name"].ToString();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {

            id.ItemsSource = new List<String> { 
                id, 
                name};
        }
```

XAML looks like:

```
<ListBox Height="168" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,21,0,0" Name="id" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" >
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
       </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

**NEW UPDATE - FOR HELP (UNRESOLVED):**
I am trying to use these strings so that I can put each item in a ListBox if more exist, opposed to just grabbing 1 item set (e.g. id, name, link).

```
   public class Datum
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help is beyond appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `ItemsSource` as something that implements `IEnumerable`.

```
id.ItemsSource = new List<String> { id };
```

You also need to adjust your binding to take in the `DataContext` since you are not passing in an object.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
```

If you want to expand outside of a simple String create a class that will wrap your contents and then bind to the given property.

```
class Person
{
     String id {get; set;}
     String name {get; set;}
}

 <ListBox Height="168" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,21,0,0" Name="id" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239" >
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
       </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Then in your code behind you can create an instance and assign as before.

```
Person p = new Person();
p.id = "id";
p.name = "name";

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(p);

id.ItemsSource = people;
```

This is a simplistic example but should provide you with what you need.

Comment: This works perfectly, but the problem is if I get multiple ID's, it seems to not want to display. I was able to add another string like "name" by doing {id, name} and it works great but it seems to not like multiple id's/names.

Any ideas on how more than 1 single ID received can be added?

Thanks again!!!

Comment: Create a class with the property name id, and do what you were trying to do before.

Comment: willmel: I have made a class (see above) but how do I run id, name and so forth through that class? Like with a JSON feed I could do "using(var stream = new MemoryStream(e.Result)" go on to running my JSON to do serializing/DataContractSerializing and have var thestring = (RootObject)DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(stream); and than run id.ItemsSource = thestring.data; (where this would put everything in the listbox).

Comment: Aaron, that did the job but I did have to add a "public" before the strings in the class. Otherwise, PERFECT! THANK YOU VERY, VERY MUCH!